# Show content of archive files in Finder preview

Tags: macos, mac, finder, quicklook

I'd like to see a preview of the contents of archive-files (.zip, .rar etc.) at the right side instead of the big ZIP-icon in the following picture when using the Finder in column-mode.

[image: Finder-column mode]

I've got a nice QuickLook-plugin for this task but still need to press CMD+Y.